# Safari keeps Crashing due to External Modification Warning

Tags: mac, macos, safari, crash, kernel

In the last 24-hours my Safari has gone haywire. I cannot access the program to even get into my Safari Preferences without getting the following message! 
Any idea how to cure this?

```
Process:               Safari [633]
Path:                  /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
Identifier:            com.apple.Safari
Version:               8.0.2 (10600.2.5)
Build Info:            WebBrowser-7600002005000000~1
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Safari [633]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-01-09 09:25:20.613 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        0A99D4C2-C7A0-2905-CF79-7294481AFF11

Sleep/Wake UUID:       4C1441A1-223E-4A41-99A9-60786ECF949D

Time Awake Since Boot: 9900 seconds
Time Since Wake:       420 seconds

Crashed Thread:        13

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020

External Modification Warnings:
Thread creation by external task.

VM Regions Near 0x20:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010758e000-000000010758f000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari

Application Specific Information:
Process Model:
Multiple Web Processes


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880eafc6 __open + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8593512b -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:] + 221
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff859382eb -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:] + 191
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8417dbbd NSImageRepNewDataFromFileURL + 470
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8417d50e +[NSImageRep _imageRepsWithContentsOfURL:expandImageContentNow:giveUpOnNetworkURLsWithoutGoodExtensions:] + 593
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8417d261 __51-[NSImageURLReferencingRepProvider representations]_block_invoke + 55
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85928006 _NSFaultInObject + 32
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8417d223 -[NSImageURLReferencingRepProvider representations] + 89
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84122af2 __45-[NSImage _usingRepresentationsPerformBlock:]_block_invoke + 47
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84122a8c -[NSImage _usingRepresentationsPerformBlock:] + 91
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff841efd47 -[NSImage representations] + 129
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84611afa -[NSImage _hasMultipleStates] + 81
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff841625db -[NSButtonCell _hasRolloverContentArt] + 43
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84162596 hasAnyRollover + 183
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8416247f -[NSButtonCell _updateMouseTracking] + 183
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8415ff74 -[NSButtonCell setControlView:] + 59
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84185127 -[NSControl initWithCoder:] + 827
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff841a8ed1 -[NSButton initWithCoder:] + 44
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84148d26 -[NSClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 561
19  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85926150 _decodeObjectBinary + 2872
20  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85927221 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1871
21  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85927435 -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 200
22  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85926150 _decodeObjectBinary + 2872
23  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff859254a6 _decodeObject + 278
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84146e0f -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 2280
25  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85926150 _decodeObjectBinary + 2872
26  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff859254a6 _decodeObject + 278
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84148739 -[NSResponder initWithCoder:] + 97
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84146590 -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 105
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84184e1f -[NSControl initWithCoder:] + 51
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff841a8ed1 -[NSButton initWithCoder:] + 44
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84148d26 -[NSClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 561
32  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85926150 _decodeObjectBinary + 2872
33  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff859254a6 _decodeObject + 278
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff841205c2 -[NSNibConnector initWithCoder:] + 106
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8412044d -[NSNibOutletConnector initWithCoder:] + 75
36  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85926150 _decodeObjectBinary + 2872
37  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85927221 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1871
38  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85927435 -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 200
39  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85926150 _decodeObjectBinary + 2872
40  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff859254a6 _decodeObject + 278
41  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8411f0e2 -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 200
42  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85926150 _decodeObjectBinary + 2872
43  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff859254a6 _decodeObject + 278
44  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8411eeb1 loadNib + 300
45  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8468cf80 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 313
46  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8411e5d5 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201
47  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x0000000107925d44 -[ToolbarController initWithBrowserWindowController:] + 164
48  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x000000010769e5b5 -[BrowserWindowControllerMac windowDidLoad] + 727
49  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8437d4e7 -[NSWindowController _windowDidLoad] + 586
50  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x00000001079a8cfe -[WindowController _windowDidLoad] + 43
51  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff843646a2 -[NSWindowController window] + 110
52  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x000000010769f053 -[BrowserWindowControllerMac showWindow:] + 66
53  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84429c0a -[NSDocument showWindows] + 93
54  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84428741 -[NSDocumentController openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:] + 470
55  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8442852c -[NSDocumentController newDocument:] + 36
56  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x00000001076967c0 +[BrowserWindowControllerMac reopen] + 256
57  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x00000001075a567f -[AppController applicationOpenUntitledFile:] + 22
58  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8435ea5a -[NSApplication _doOpenUntitled] + 424
59  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84297b91 __58-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:]_block_invoke + 252
60  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff845a1389 __97-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 + 140
61  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff845a0d81 -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsIgnoringExpendable:withCompletionHandler:] + 798
62  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8413fee6 -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:registeringAsReady:completionHandler:] + 331
63  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8413fc69 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 561
64  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8413f6b5 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 244
65  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85930458 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 290
66  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff859302c9 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
67  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff84d4599c aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 531
68  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff84d45719 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 31
69  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff84d45623 aeProcessAppleEvent + 295
70  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8e7a837e AEProcessAppleEvent + 56
71  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8413bd76 _DPSNextEvent + 2665
72  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8413ae80 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
73  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x000000010760ead0 -[BrowserApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 246
74  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8412ee23 -[NSApplication run] + 594
75  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8411a2d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
76  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff867d15c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880ec22e kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d848a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880eb946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880eb946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880eb946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880eb946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880eb946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:: WebCore: IconDatabase
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880ec5d6 pread + 10
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff8683c855 readDbPage + 117
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff8683af92 sqlite3PagerAcquire + 1314
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff8692d2dc checkList + 156
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff8692db51 checkTreePage + 1057
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff8692dc84 checkTreePage + 1364
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff868764ac sqlite3VdbeExec + 67324
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff868643df sqlite3_step + 735
8   com.apple.WebCore               0x00000001091c4bc9 WebCore::SQLiteStatement::step() + 73
9   com.apple.WebCore               0x0000000109815a2c WebCore::IconDatabase::checkIntegrity() + 108
10  com.apple.WebCore               0x00000001091c4314 WebCore::IconDatabase::performOpenInitialization() + 116
11  com.apple.WebCore               0x00000001091c39b5 WebCore::IconDatabase::iconDatabaseSyncThread() + 325
12  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x000000010837ea9f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc42fc _pthread_body + 131
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc4279 _pthread_start + 176
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880eb946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880eb946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:

Thread 11:: com.apple.CoreAnimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880e652e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880e569f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff86e82d63 CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 198
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff86e82c96 thread_fun + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc42fc _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc4279 _pthread_start + 176
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880e652e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff880e569f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836b6b14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836b5fdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff836b5838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8d588d20 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85976b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc42fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc4279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc24b1 thread_start + 13

**Thread 13 Crashed:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83dc2695 _pthread_mutex_lock + 87
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d386b78 vfprintf_l + 28
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8d37f620 fprintf + 186
3   ???                             0x00000001103615dc 0 + 4566947292
Thread 13 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff73cb41d8  rcx: 0x00007fff73cb41f0  rdx: 0x00000000000000a0
  rdi: 0x00007fff73cb41f0  rsi: 0x00007fff83dc2b14  rbp: 0x000000011035de30  rsp: 0x000000011035ddb0
   r8: 0x0000000110365000   r9: 0x0000000000000054  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff73cb36b8  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff83dc2695  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000020

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14**
```

Comment: If you boot into safe mode (hold the Shift key down when you hear the startup chime) can you run safari?

Comment: Or perhaps delete the saved state folder at ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState